# Windows 11 BootCamp installation failing

Tags: macos, windows, imac, bootcamp, intel

I have an 2019 Intel iMac on which I tried to install Windows 11 following instructions from [this page](https://machow2.com/windows-11-mac-boot-camp/). These instructions include disabling the TPM check.

I used a (Dutch) Windows 11 ISO, which was downloaded from the [Microsoft page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11).

I did let BootCamp create a 128GB partition.

Installation started well, but after a while, at the stage of copying Windows files, the installation stopped showing an error.

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the error or at least an error code for us to debug.

Comment: @RishonJR I updated my question with a screenshot showing the error.

Comment: IFAIK, Apple does not support the installation of Windows 11 on any Intel Mac. The Boot Camp Assistant installed on your Mac can be used to download a version of the Windows Support Software (which includes drivers) for your Mac. IMO, the Boot Camp Assistant should not be used to install Windows 11. Microsoft has [published](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e) that the `dism` command can be used to install Windows 11. IMO, a method which uses this command is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After surfing the internet and testing several complicated methods, I finally found a [solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253391725) to another problem that takes this over. The method is simple and tricky: manipulating a Windows 10 installation iso file to install Windows 11 instead. This will also jump over the TPM checking and no need to run regedit!

---

Below is a copy of the posted solution. Note that the author (Apple Support Community user MacWindowsOS) states that what is posted below came from Reddit.

### [Guide] Windows 11 clean install through Boot Camp Assistant

**The Problem:**

Trying to install Windows 11 through Boot Camp Assistant (BCA) with an official Windows 11 ISO simply results in the assistant failing with the error message "Couldn't download Windows Support Software because it is not currently available from the server". This is because the Windows Support Software not only contains drivers for installing within Windows, but also contains drivers that are used during the Windows Pre-Installation Environment (WinPE), and Apple doesn't have drivers for Windows 11. Switch to a Windows 10 ISO, and the problem goes away - but then you're installing Windows 10.

**The Solution:**

We are able to workaround this issue by retaining WinPE from the Windows 10 ISO, but using the OS install archive from a Windows 11 ISO. This allows you to install Windows 11 on your Intel-based Apple device using the Windows 10 installer. This method also bypasses both the TPM and Secure Boot requirements.

**The Process:**

You need the following:

- A working Windows installation
- A copy of a Windows 10 ISO (either from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) or from the [Media Creation Tool](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209))
- A copy of a Windows 11 ISO (from the [Windows 11-specific Media Creation Tool](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2156295))
- [ImgBurn](https://download.imgburn.com/SetupImgBurn_2.5.8.0.exe), or a similar ISO editor installed (although my instructions are for ImgBurn)

Once you have all of that, do the following:

1. Create a folder somewhere in your computer (for simplicity, I'll just assume you're creating it in your downloads folder) and name it `Win11_21H2_BC` (or similar, it doesn't matter what you name it)
2. Mount and open the Windows 10 ISO
3. Copy **all** files from the mounted disk image into the folder you created in step 1
4. Unmount the Windows 10 ISO
5. Navigate to `FolderCreatedInStep1\sources\`, and **delete** the file named either `install.wim` or `install.esd`
6. Mount the Windows 11 ISO
7. Navigate to `ESD-ISO\sources\`, and copy the file named either `install.esd` (most common) or `install.wim` (less common) to `FolderCreatedInStep1\sources\`.

   1. If your file is named `install.wim`, rename it to `install.esd`.
8. Unmount the Windows 11 ISO
9. Open ImgBurn, and select **Create image file from files/folders**
10. In the top window, select the icon that looks like a folder with a magnifying glass over it (Browse for a folder) and select the folder you created in step 1. Don't open it, just select it.
11. Then, to the right of the destination input box, click the same folder/magnifying glass icon and set a name and location for your output ISO file.
12. Click the large folder to disk image icon. You will receive a message telling you that you've "only selected 1 folder". Click **Yes**.
13. Another message box will then pop up - Set the volume label to whatever you want or leave it as the defaults. The program will then create your modified Windows 10 disk image, and play an obnoxious sound effect once it's complete.

Then, transfer the disk image you just made to your Apple device. You can now follow the standard procedure to create the Windows partition and download the support software. **Note that when your device boots into the Windows installer, it will be the Windows 10 installer. This is fine. It will install Windows 11, not Windows 10.**

Comment: This is a duplicate answer to [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/463647/119271).  which suffers from severe content issues. Can you fix with an [edit] keeping in mind that the answer should be able to stand on its own without reliance on another site?

Comment: @DavidAnderson - I flagged for mod attention to merge/link the two questions.  The error code in both are the same (merge reason)