# Error 0x80070070 installing Windows 11 on BOOTCAMP

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, install

This error is reported several times but with no answer anywhere, such as [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446267/windows-11-bootcamp-installation-failing) and [there](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/10lr3uc/trouble_installing_windows_11_via_boot_camp_on). I tried to install Windows 11 on a Macbook 2017 Retina using Boot Camp Assistant. The device had previously have Windows 11 installed besides Ventura. I give it a 300GB space and everything goes well until I change the registry to bypass the TPM check, and it starts copying files but file copy stops at 5% showing this message:

```
Windows cannot install required files. Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070070
```

I wonder if the error could be bypassed if Boot Camp installs Windows from USB instead of the internal drive. I tried to manipulate the app content of `Info.plist` to force it use flash disk, but was stopped by the read-only error.